# How can I keep the smoothness of an object when exporting it?

Tags: modeling, export, edit-mode, faces

I currently have a model which I downloaded off the internet. This is a quick screenshot of it:

[image]

The problem with this gun model is that neither the gun barrel or top part of the body is supposed to be like it looks; it's supposed to be round. I saw a few guides on Youtube and tried manually selecting and smoothing groups of edges. This is how it is supposed to look:

[image]

However, when I exported as an .obj to 3D Builder, it lost its smoothness and maintained its original appearance as so:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Hi, welcome. How did you "smooth" those faces? It clearly appears that the exported geometry is not smoothed enough, you could have to apply modifiers, before, eg. Detail more what you did exactly...

Comment: 3D printers have no smooth shading. They can only print the faces in the model. You can try a subdivision surface modifier, but you will probably have to remake the barrel of the gun.

Comment: hi do u know any answer? i have the same problem as u had, thanks!